# añadir replace a ultimo archivo sin termino

Tags: python, windows, script, replace

saludos a todos, el problema que tengo hoy es simple pero no caigo para resolverlo, lo primero tengo estos archivos:

> _V6A9103,_V6A9143,_V6A9154,_V6A9197,_V6A9201,_V6A9223,_V6A9239,_V6A9260,_V6A9267,_V6A9298

Bueno pues yo tengo puesto un replace en todos de esta manera (la variable archivos son los archivos de arriba):

```
archivos2 = archivos.replace(",", ".JPG,")
```

Esto me hace que el output sea esto:

> _V6A9103.JPG,_V6A9143.JPG,_V6A9154.JPG,_V6A9197.JPG,_V6A9201.JPG,_V6A9223.JPG,_V6A9239.JPG,_V6A9260.JPG,_V6A9267.JPG,_V6A9298

Como veis todo bien, pero el problema es que el ULTIMO ARCHIVO se queda sin el replace y por lo cual no me sirve para lo que quiero, alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que archivos es una lista de strings con los nombre de archivos, puedes hacer:

```
archivos2 = [archivo + ".jpg" for archivo in archivos]
```

Ahora, si archivos es un string que contiene todos los nombres, puedes usar:

```
# Dividir la cadena en una lista de elementos
elementos = archivos.split(",")

# Agregar ".jpg" al final de cada elemento de la lista
elementos2 = [elemento + ".jpg" for elemento in elementos]

# Volver a unir los elementos de la lista en una sola cadena
archivos2 = ",".join(elementos2)
```